# How to perfectly implement comment option in android app by json POST method

Tags: android, comments

I have a news related json api url and i have been implemented comment post to url but not showing posted parameter comment from the response in same news id in textview. I also used shared prefs but not works well. Please anyone help me.Thanks.Here is my code:

```
        holder.btnpost.setOnClickListener( view -> {

                    String comment = holder.inputcomment.getText().toString();
                    sp = new SharedPreferencesHandler( context );
                    session = new SessionManager( this.context );

                    if (!comment.isEmpty() && session.isLoggedIn()) {
                        commentPost( comment );

                       } else if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
                        Toast.makeText( context, "Please Sign in first!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText( context, "Please write something!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    }

                } );

            //post method
              private void commentPost(final String comment) {
                sp = new SharedPreferencesHandler( context );
                commentDataList = new ArrayList<>();
                String tag_comments = "comment";

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest( Request.Method.POST, commentURL + currentId, response -> {

                    Log.d( "TAG", "response = " + response );

                    if (response != null) {`enter code here`
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject( response );
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray( "success" );
                            if (jsonArray != null && jsonArray.length() > 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {`enter code here`
                                    JSONObject dataOjbect = jsonArray.getJSONObject( i );
                                    String mComment = dataOjbect.getString( "comment" );
                                    Comment mCommentData = new Comment( mComment );
                                    commentDataList.add( mCommentData );
                                    displayComment.setText( mCommentData.getComment() );

                                }
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Toast.makeText( context, "Commented", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    }
                },
                        error -> {
                            Log.d( "TAG", "Error = " + error );
                            Toast.makeText( context, "No comment posted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

                        } )
         {
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                        params.put( "comment", comment );
                        return params;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                        SharedPreferences mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences( "radiobanglany", Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
                        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                        headers.put( "Accept", "application/json" );
                        headers.put( "Authorization", 

"Bearer"+mPrefs.getString("token", "" ) );   
                          return headers;    
    }   

   };
```

AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue( stringRequest, "tag_comments");

```
    }
```

Comment: post the code for what you have tried?and what actually wants in output?

Comment: @userI ok i edited my question.